# AWS Lambda function stops being able to connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tcp

I have a Lambda function that I  run every hour using a cloudwatch scheduled event.

When triggered the function makes an HTTP request to a service on the internet and then, having received the response, performs some SQL queries inside our VPC before making a couple more HTTP requests to the same service.

Because of the SQL database, the Lambda must run in our VPC.  So in order to connect out to the internet, I've included our NAT gateway subnet among the Lambda's VPC subnets.

I've tried destroying and creating this Lambda function several times with the same result each time:

It runs as expected for a few/several hours.  And then, after that, it never succeeds again because the attempt to make a TCP connection for the first HTTP request reliably fails.   Only after I create a whole new Lambda function with the same code and configuration is it able to connect to the internet.

How can this be?

Comment: Why are you configuring multiple subnets? If you do that then, I believe, multiple ENIs will be attached to the Lambda, one per subnet. You probably need the Lambda to be in one, and only one, private subnet, and that subnet should have a default route to a NAT. Also, it takes some time to attach/detach ENIs so your Lambda function should be sensitive to this possibility and retry outbound network connections.

Comment: Sounds very strange. What error messages are reported in CloudWatch Logs?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein:  Just my own application logs about timing out while trying to connect.  Or, if I set the socket timeout too high, then the lambda function itself times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've included our NAT gateway subnet among the Lambda's VPC subnets.

That is definitely a misconfiguration.

Lambda functions that need Internet access need to be on subnets whose default route *points to* a NAT Gateway -- none of which can also be a subnet that has an actual NAT Gateway on it.  A NAT Gateway never provides NAT services to any instance on the same subnet as the gateway itself.